# Sed command to replace a variable's value in a robot file with another variable's value in current script?

Tags: sed

Content of robot file *variables.robot*:

```
*** Variables ***
${SCREEN}                               NO
```

Content of robot file *variables.robot* below

```
*** Variables ***
${SCREEN}                               NO
```

I try to replace value of ${SCREEN} variable in robot file with the the content of the SCREENSHOT_CHOICE (=YES) variable in current *groovy* script.
I tried to execute such code

```
sed -i "s/^\\(${SCREEN}\\).*/${SCREENSHOT_CHOICE}/"   variables.robot
```

Finally, I want to gain below result

```
*** Variables ***
${SCREEN}                              YES
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E "/^\\$\{SCREEN}/s/NO$/${SCREENSHOT_CHOICE}/" variables.robot
*** Variables ***
${SCREEN}                               YES
```